# change UINavigationItem titleView text

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, titleview

I'm using custom titleView for navigation bar in viewDidLoad, here is my code:

```
UILabel *titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 220, 44)];
titleView.text = @"Hello";
titleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

But I want to change this title text later programmatically, I tried couple ways with no success.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView.text = @"Loading...";
self.navigationItem.title = @"Loading...";
```

How do I change the title text in custom titleView ?

Answer (score 1):

If the initial code works you should allocate a new label, set its text and reset it and that should probably work.

Alternatively store the label as a property and try setting its title from self.label.text = @"..."